# B2C Reset Password Flow not working from Microsoft docs

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

I am following the configuration sample provided by microsoft for the custom policy templates and the starter pack (note the starter pack still has all templates of the API's page layout on version 1.0.0).
Have updated the flows to be on template 2.1.4(latest stable), and well as 1.2.1 or the other recommended versions by Microsoft on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#migrating-to-page-layout.

However, every time I click on the forgot password link after uploading my 3 custom policies (base, extension, signupsignin), I get the following error logged into my appInsights instance:

A claim could not be found for lookup claim with id "alternativeSecurityId" defined in technical profile with id "AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" policy "B2C_1A_signup_signin" of tenant "yourTenant.onmicrosoft.com".

Note: I put in "yourtenant" here but it is obviously not my tenant name.
The login flow is working correctly as well as any of the other customizations I have made on the policy.
I even went back as to setup the policy to not have any customizations, and just try to set up the password reset flow still with no functioning sample.

Unfortunately not much info is out there helping me troubleshoot this error so wanted to ask the community for some pointers or if someone has a working example for this portion of the reset policy, if not Just considering creating a standard userJourney for the reset password as the recommended version is obviously not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it to work after 2 days of trial and error. So there is a step missing on the instructions. After the claims exchange for the forgot password, but before the invocation of the subjourney, you actually have to call the claims exchange. Having said that, I did this:

```html
<!--This step will trigger the actual forgot password exchange and show us the page from the integrated policy.-->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordXchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" /> 
      </ClaimsExchanges><!--Id must be unique-->
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

In case someone wants to correct something or send an update or suggestion on this, this is how my user journey ended up looking like, and my subjourney:

```html
<UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="CustomSignUpOrSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!-- HRD initialization -->
        <!-- Changes based off of  <UserJourney Id="HRD_Internal">  -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="HRD" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="HRD_Function" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <Preconditions>
            <!--
           <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
             <Value>idp</Value>
             <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
           </Precondition>
           -->
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>idpHint</Value>
              <Value></Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="TestExchange1" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <!--
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>idp</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            -->
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>idpHint</Value>
              <Value></Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="TestExchange1" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ConcentrixAD-OpenIdConnect" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!--This step will trigger the actual forgot password exchange and show us the page from the integrated policy.-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges> <!--Id must be unique-->
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>idpHint</Value>
              <Value>okta</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="HintedOktaSAMLExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Okta-SAML2" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId).
              This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
              using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent
              in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect
                 from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist
                 (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="10" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="11" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
 </UserJourneys>
 <SubJourneys>
    <SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
        <OrchestrationSteps>
            <!--Validate user's email address. Run this step only when user resets the password-->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <!--Collect and persist a new password. Run this step only when user resets the password-->
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
        </OrchestrationSteps>
    </SubJourney>
 </SubJourneys>
```